# What are 'aliased coefficients'?

Tags: r, regression

While building a regression model in R (`lm`), I am frequently getting this message

```
"there are aliased coefficients in the model"
```

What exactly does it mean?

Also, due to this `predict()` is also giving a warning.

Though it's just a warning, I want to know how can we detect/remove aliased coefficients before building a model.

Also, what are the probable consequences of neglecting this warning?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I suspect this is not an error of `lm`, but rather `vif` (from package `car`). If so, I believe you have ran into [perfect multicollinearity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity). For instance

```
x1 <- rnorm( 100 )
x2 <- 2 * x1
y <- rnorm( 100 )
vif( lm( y ~ x1 + x2 ) )
```

produces your error.

In this context, ''alias'' refers to the variables that are linearly dependent on others (i.e. cause perfect multicollinearity).

The first step towards the solution is to identify which variable(s) are the culprit(s). Run

```
alias( lm( y ~ x1 + x2 ) )
```

to see an example.

Comment: Thanks. Is 'multicollinearity' same as having 'aliased coefficients' ?

Comment: @MohitVerma : In this terminology ''alias'' refers to the variables that are linearly dependent (i.e. cause perfect multicollinearity). See http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/alias.html . I update the answer with this.

Answer (score 6):

This often comes up when you have singularities in your regression `X'X` matrix (NA values in the summary of the regression output).

Base R `lm()` allows for singular values/perfect multicollinearity as the default is `singular.ok = TRUE`. Other packages/functions are more conservative.

For example, for the `linearHypothesis()` function in the `car` package, the default is `singular.ok = FALSE`. If you have perfect multicollinearity in your regression, `linearHypothesis()` will return an error "there are aliased coefficients in the model". To deal with this error, set `singular.ok = TRUE`. Be careful, however, as doing this may mask perfect multicollinearity in your regression.

Answer (score 3):

maybe to good to know for some: I got this error as well when I added dummies to a regression. R automatically omit one dummy, but this causes an error in the vif test. so a solution, for some, might be removing one dummy manually.